# Can I restrain Qt to only use bundled fonts and never rely on system fonts?

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, embedded-resource

In our **Qt5** application we *bundle a custom font as a resource*. We use only this font in the application, and rely on no other fonts.

The font we use has a whooping **128** variations (regular, bold, black, extrabold, extrabold italic, semibold, thin, condensed etc). and we have naturally decided to only bundle the tiny subset of those variations that we actually use.

To make matters more complex, the font we use exists in several **versions** with small changes between them.

On my development computer I have installed all the 128 variations of one version of the font in the OS itself while on the clients that run the software we *can't really tell if the fonts are present or not* in their OS, and if present, in which version.

We have experienced cases where the fonts looks **severely different** between my development computer and on the end clients. We use the font in a virtual keyboard widget and some symbols on the keys show up OK on my computer while they are missing (showing the empty box character) on the client.

So my question is, can we somehow *restrain the font system in Qt* to only use the fonts provided by the resources bundled with the program? That would mean that any reference to system default fonts such as Arial would simply result in our font to be used instead, or simply denied with an error.

Any insights and tips are warmly welcomed.

Thanks!